# Create "table style" ListView in UWP and XAML (C#)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I'm wondering if there is any way I can create a "table like" ListView in a UWP Windows 10 app? I need some sort of table where I can allow a user to browse and select files and then put the selected files into a list, sort of like a details view that you see in Windows explorer with column headers and rows that I can insert programmatically like:

```
string[] item = { "D:\\Music\\MyAudioFile.mp3", "MP3", "12MB" }
listview1.Items.Add(item);
```

Anyone have any ideas what I can use for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Lindexi, that pointed me in the right direction... Here is the code I got working...

C# backend code:

```
        // Create a new StackPanel to insert as a ListViewItem
        StackPanel myStack = new StackPanel();
        myStack.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        myStack.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        myStack.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        // Create new StackPanel "Child" elements with alignment and width
        ListViewItem lv1 = new ListViewItem();
        lv1.Content = "Test Content";
        lv1.Width = 400;
        lv1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        lv1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

        // Create new StackPanel "Child" elements with alignment and width
        ListViewItem lv2 = new ListViewItem();
        lv2.Content = "Test Content";
        lv2.Width = 100;
        lv2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        lv2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

        // Create new StackPanel "Child" elements with alignment and width
        ListViewItem lv3 = new ListViewItem();
        lv3.Content = "Test Content";
        lv3.Width = 100;
        lv3.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        lv3.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

        // Create new StackPanel "Child" elements with alignment and width
        ListViewItem lv4 = new ListViewItem();
        lv4.Content = "Test Content";
        lv4.Width = 100;
        lv4.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        lv4.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

        // Create new StackPanel "Child" elements with alignment and width
        ListViewItem lv5 = new ListViewItem();
        lv5.Content = "Test Content";
        lv5.Width = 250;
        lv5.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        lv5.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

        // Create new StackPanel "Child" elements with alignment and width
        ListViewItem lv6 = new ListViewItem();
        lv6.Content = "Test Content";
        lv6.Width = 250;
        lv6.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        lv6.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

        // Add "Child" elements for the new StackPanel
        myStack.Children.Add(lv1);
        myStack.Children.Add(lv2);
        myStack.Children.Add(lv3);
        myStack.Children.Add(lv4);
        myStack.Children.Add(lv5);
        myStack.Children.Add(lv6);

        // Add the new StackPanel as a ListViewItem control
        MusicQueue.Items.Insert(1, myStack);
```

XAML Code:

```
        <ListView Name="MusicQueue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ListViewHeaderItem Width="400">Filename</ListViewHeaderItem>
                    <ListViewHeaderItem Width="100">Format</ListViewHeaderItem>
                    <ListViewHeaderItem Width="100">Size</ListViewHeaderItem>
                    <ListViewHeaderItem Width="100">Duration</ListViewHeaderItem>
                    <ListViewHeaderItem Width="250">Artist</ListViewHeaderItem>
                    <ListViewHeaderItem Width="250">Title</ListViewHeaderItem>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
```

Of course this is probably not going to be the most efficient way to manually add an item to a ListView stacked horizontally, but it works which is most important :)

If anyone does know a quicker way to do this with less code please let me know :)

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataGrid in UWP.

But you also can use DataTemplate in ListView, and you can use blow code to solve the width is too small.

```
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                            Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The lib you can use is :https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid

And https://liftcodeplay.com/2015/10/24/datagrid-alternatives-in-uwp/

If you can spend money, you can use https://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp/sfdatagrid